# Sobreescribir Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

mi duda es la siguiente, yo tengo una array con un object, y no se como sobreescribir el valor del object me refiero,

```
array = [
        usuario: 21312321,
        constraseña: "erica"
    },...]
```

lo que me interesaria seria editar el "erica", desde ya muchas gracias.
PD: Estoy usando Jquery

Comment: seguro que esa sintáxis es correcta? ya que un arreglo es var arreglo = [el1, el2, el3] y un objeto es var obj = {name: 'bla', age: 24}

Comment: Si, la sintaxis del array es correcta, lo que escribi fue solo un ejemplo, use el array para otras cosas y funciona a la perfeccion, tengo la duda solamente de cual es el comando que necesito para sobreescribir una propiedad de un array, muchas gracias

Comment: Me había olvidado. Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)! Por favor visita nuesto [tour]. En caso que de necesites ayuda por favor visita nuestro [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No logro comprender exactamente a que te refieres (además a tu ejemplo le falta el inicio de la llave curva `{`).

Pero imaginemos que este es tu `array`:

```
array = [
  {
    usuario: 21312321,
    contraseña: "erica",
  },
  {
    usuario: 12154156,
    contraseña: "1234",
  }
}
```

Para acceder a la contraseña de tu primer usuario (tanto lectura como escritura) en el array sería cualquiera de estas dos lineas:

```
array[0].contraseña = "paula"
console.log(array[0].contraseña)
array[0]["contraseña"] = "paula"
console.log(array[0]["contraseña"])
```

Avísame si te sirve esta respuesta o tu pregunta era otra.

Comment: creo que la pregunta es como sobre escribir un valor especifico, es decir cambiarlo por otro

Comment: @AlfredoPaz, pues en mi respuesta ya incluyo como acceder (tanto lectura como escritura) a la variable mediante `array[0].contraseña` y `array[0]["contraseña"]`. No es así?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo

```
var data = [{
  name: 'Alfredo',
  age: 28
}]

console.log(data.name = "Beta")
```

Como observas dentro del `console.log()` accedo al nombre del objeto y posteriormente para entrar al valor lo hago como `obj.clave` y para asignar un nuevo valor lo hago con `=nuevovalor`

Con la desestructuración de objetos en ES6 puedes hacerlo mas simple mira este ejemplo

```
var data = {
  name: 'Alfredo',
  age: 28
}

var {name, age} = data

console.log(name = "jorge")
console.log(age = 89)
```

Comment: El primer ejemplo no cambiará el atributo name, lo que hará es añadir un atributo name a la variable data

Comment: gracias por la observación @KacosPro me pondré a revisar

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haría de la siguente manera:

```js
let array = [
  {
    usuario: 21312321,
    constrasena: "erica"
  },
  {
    usuario: 1234,
    contrasena: "acire"
  }
]
// nuevaContrasena = nueva contraseña
//array = array a iterar
//usuario = usuario para la comparacion
function updateHash(nuevaContrasena, array, usuario) {

  array.forEach((elemento) => { // recoremos el elemento
    if (elemento.usuario == usuario) { // validamos el usuario al asignarle la contraseña
      elemento.contrasena = nuevaContrasena // modificamos la contraseña
    }
  })

}
console.log(array)
updateHash("nuevapass", array, 1234)
console.log(array)
```

así sabes a que usuario le vas a modificar la contraseña.